# Deployment target screen is not coming while click on run button?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]In my android studio deployment target screen is not coming after I updated my gradle. When I click on run button nothing is coming only one msg is showing on down message bar is **"run selected configuration"**. I am stuck here like two hours tried with version changing of gradle and all but still facing the same issue. Please if anyone has any solution to this, help me.

[image: Showing event log when I click on run button]

[image: Edit configuration window]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error or window that appears?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: What happens when you click "play" or "run" button, nothing happens? Can you check and also post what do you see if you open "Event Log" (bottom right tab). Alos post what you see after clicking on "Run selected configuration". Can you check as well to the right of the word "app" and to the left of the "run"/"play" green button there is an arrow pointind downwards, click on it and click on "Edit configuration" and post a screenshot of what you see there.

Comment: denis as you said I have updated my question with required images

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, actually, my adb.exe file was not showing the SDK-platform tools. That's the main reason why deploy target screen is not working. Now I uninstalled and install again platform-tools. It is working fine now.